# Magento 2.2.3 problem with invoiced order, can´t edit order

Tags: orders, shipping, invoice, shipment

I have a store with two payment methods.

- ProxyPay - Generate an order ***without*** shipment or invoice with status equal ***Processing***. When Magecomp 1.0.0 detect payment, state of order is passed to ***Complete***.
- PayPal - Generate an order ***with*** one invoice with status equal ***Proccesing***, without shipment and order status equal ***Processing***. When payment is detected, state of invoice is passed to ***Paid*** and order status keeps like ***Proccesing***.

I try to add some code in Magecomp Proxypay plugin for keep state of Order and create a new invoice with ***Paid*** status as initial status. This work well, but when end user go to admin panel and try to create a new shipment for pass Order status from ***Proccesing*** to ***Complete*** a blanck screen apears and process never conclud.

Look that PayPal solution create a Order with Invoice and if wnd user try to create a shipment this proccess is conclud normaly.

Below, my code to add a invoice into order.

```php
if ($orderObj->canEdit() && !empty($orderObj->getItems())) {
    $items = [];
    foreach ($orderObj->getItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductType() == "simple") {
            $items[$item->getItemId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        }
    }
    try {
        /**
         * @var $invoice Invoice
         */
        $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($orderObj, $items);
        $invoice->setShippingAmount($orderObj->getShippingAmount());
        $invoice->setSubtotal($orderObj->getSubtotal());
        $invoice->setBaseSubtotal($orderObj->getBaseSubtotal());
        $invoice->setGrandTotal($orderObj->getGrandTotal());
        $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($orderObj->getBaseGrandtotal());
        $invoice->setState(Invoice::STATE_PAID);
        $invoice->register();
        $transactionSave = $this->transaction->addObject($invoice)
            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
        $transactionSave->save();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $storeManager->info($exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I investigate the blanck screen and i found this in `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` :

```php
/**
 * Retrieve order edit availability
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function canEdit()
{
    if ($this->canUnhold()) {
        return false;
    }

    $state = $this->getState();
    if ($this->isCanceled() ||
        $this->isPaymentReview() ||
        $state === self::STATE_COMPLETE ||
        $state === self::STATE_CLOSED
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->hasInvoices()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->canEdit()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_EDIT) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In other words, if order have an invoice, I can't edit the order.

Any help or ideia for this problem. Why PayPal works and my soltion not works?